# What is a disabled windows account exactly?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, administrator

While tinkering with windows account (locally, not in a domain) I stumbled onto something I don't understand

I created a local windows session (let's call it Joe), this session has admin rights

Then, with my real admin session (call it Bob) I created a scheduled task that executes 5sec after logon with the highest privileges using Joe's credentials, this task executes `net user Joe /active:no`

This result in a "one time use" session that will disable itself after logon and can only be re-enabled by Bob

Now if I log in to Joe's session, I will have admin rights, for example I can start PowerShell as admin, and it will work, but why? How can the account still have the right to start something as admin if it is disabled?
I'll even ask: why can it start anything at all?

Does the "disabled" state only take effect after all the sessions are closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it not be able to start programs? Starting a process does not require a new login. In the most basic case, it simply inherits the access token of the parent process and that's it. The access token is self-contained.

Why can an admin process start? Because the user session with admin rights *also* already exists. With UAC, both the "regular" and admin access tokens are created when the user is logged in.

The *disabled* state only comes into play when signing in. IIRC this also applies to lock screens.

For most operations, the security authority (local account database or Active Directory or the like) is not consulted at all, because this would critically harm performance with domain-joined machines. The security-critical data structures reside in protected memory and cannot be altered, so the operating system can trust them.

Comment: So, what are the security implication of a disabled account still able to do things? Are the token infinite, or do they expire after some time?

Comment: @TheStaticTurtle - Realistically you have found an edge case. The account wasn’t locked when it was logged into and it having elevated permissions didn’t change when it was locked. To be honest a experienced Administrator wouldn’t just stop at locking an account.  They would also remove its permissions.

Comment: @TheStaticTurtle The tokens do not expire. If you want a user gone, you must administratively logout their sessions. There is no built-in tooling available to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree this is an edge case and I would also remove the permissions